# QGraphicsItem unselect redraw problem

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, scene, unselect

Very simple Qt GUI application:

- On the scene I have multiple circles implemented as QGraphicsItem
- boundingRect returns square around
  this circle.
- Method 'shape' is not overridden.

The problem appears when in paint() method I've added:

```
if (isSelected()) {
    painter->drawRect(re);
}
```

Selection is drawn well, but unselection doesn't cause redrawing. At log level I can see that item really lost selection flag. 
Calling update() from itemChange is useless also. 
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 days I returned back to this problem and discovered that my QGraphicsItem constructed with 
`setCacheMode(DeviceCoordinateCache);`
 OMG! Stupid mistake, when this line was removed (by default QGraphicsItem::NoCache used) selection is redrawn well.

Comment: can u explain me why this flag setCacheMode is creating the problem ..right now im facing the same problem. if i set the QGraphicsProxyWidget with this flag its not showing the label properly untill i set the viewport to opengl.

Comment: @Wagmare it is rather simple - because border around item is not appeared in cache. Cache of DeviceCoordinateCache level is too good that is why changes of border is not appeared in it.

Comment: thx for much useful  reply.. so how i can use cache on QGraphicsProxyWidget as i need to add more than thousand items its required to use cache.?

Comment: borders are visible but only  the pixmap is not visible..some times partially visible i some areas ..

Comment: @Wagmare try to change CacheMode level (see at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsitem.html#CacheMode-enum) or totally remove `setCacheMode`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to change the default QGraphicsView::MinimalViewportUpdate to FullViewportUpdate with setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);

Or you can call scene()->update(); from the item to schedule a repaint.

One of them was required at least when I kept changing the QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents flag on an item.